# How to declare a function with variable arguments to be stdcall?

Tags: c, gcc, calling-convention, stdcall

Now I am designing a function `f(index,...)` which will call *#index* entry in a function array passing the rest of parameters. If you see the function array as a service list, `f` acts like a service distributer.

`f` is written in assembly. It pops the first parameter `index` then calculates the corresponding target function address and **jmp** to it.

If I pass `n` parameters to `f`, the stack just holds `n-1` ones when returning from the target function, because `index` was popped midway. For this reason, I cannot use `cdecl` convention, or the caller will clean the stack for `n` parameters by mistake.

`stdcall` should works. But the problem is that, since `f` has **variable arguments**, gcc seems `__attribute__((stdcall)) f(index,...)` unreasonable and reverts it back to `cdecl`.

So please could any one tell me how to declare `f` to be `stdcall` ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using stdcall would solve your problem, since you would have to restore the stack anyway for your function to find the return address on the stack.

Rather than popping `index` from the stack, just leave it there. And either modify your target functions to ignore the first parameter, or move all the other parameters one position to the left before calling target function

Comment: Surely modifying the target functions to add a dummy parameters works, but not beautiful enough. And I cannot *move all the other parameters...* because `f` didn't know how many parameters passed in total.
`stdcall` should works. In the implementation of `f`, it runs **leave** to recover `esp` and `ebp`, then **pop** the return address to register *#1*, saves `index` then replace it with *#1* (now the stack is constructed well). Finally it **jmp** to the target according to `index`. `stdcall` of the target will correctly clean the rest `n-1` parameters.

Comment: Does 'f' have to be thread safe? Wrap `f` in a macro that saves `index` to a global variable before calling `f`.  Or you could maybe use some inline assembly to pass `index` in a register.